# Should all copies of a repeated answer be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, duplicate-answers

Earlier today I was searching for a piece of technology that I knew existed, and my search turned up 3 SO questions asking for the same thing I was looking for, and none of them had the answer.  (Each had an existing answer that was an indirect way to accomplish the asker's goal, not exactly what the asker wanted.)  When I finally found the project I was looking for, I went back and answered those three SO questions with a link to the product in question, to help the original askers.

An hour or so later, a moderator had deleted all my answers, stating, "Please [don't post duplicate answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions). If the questions are the same, pick the best one to answer fully on site and then flag the other(s) as duplicates. If they're not the same, then tailor your answer to the specifics of each question."

I have read the page linked to in the moderator's comment, and I now see what I should have done.  **But my question instead is:  What do I do now?**  It's *not* the case that *all but one* of my answers were deleted; all were deleted.  So now none of the 3 original questions has the answer that I think is actually the most helpful answer (which is why I posted it).

There does not seem to be an option for asking the moderator to reverse their action, or even any way to communicate with the moderator at all.

Comment: "There does not seem to be an option for asking the moderator to reverse their action, or even any way to communicate with the moderator at all." - Well, besides meta of course which you seems to have found just fine. But step 1 should be verifying if you are simply misunderstanding what you are seeing, you know... The mod does not need to be involved in that process. Only when it becomes clear that a mistake has been made.

Comment: "any way to communicate with the moderator at all" - you can use the "Flag" link under your post.  Though as noted below, the answers are unlikely to be restored as-is.

Comment: @RyanM Yeah, I saw that link, but I didn't click it because it seemed confrontational/arrogant, since it would be flagging the (very experienced) moderator's post with the "serious problem" flag.  I'm not arguing with you, I'm just saying it did not seem at face value like The Thing I Was Supposed To Do.

Comment: You would want to flag your own post, rather than the moderator's comment.  Comment flags are "this comment should be deleted."  Post flags are basically "I need a moderator to do something for me that only a moderator can do."  Often it's a serious problem, but sometimes it can be something like "hey, you deleted this answer for being link-only, but I've fixed it now - could you undelete it?"   You could also send a polite flag along the lines of "Hi, I'm sorry for posting the same thing multiple times - could you let me know in a mod message if there was a specific reason all were deleted?"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pick **one** question to answer, then flag the others as duplicates. That's the action that the moderator is asking you to take.

Deleting all of the answers seems sensible since <s>the mod doesn't know Which Answer™ you want to be the authoritative answer</s> they all read like link-only answers.

[image]
[image]
[image]

You *could* flag one of your answers in a custom flag to say that you're choosing it as The Answer you wish to then use to close the other two questions - that'd be the way you could get a mod's attention.  Or you could repost it.

With new information I'd strongly recommend that you repost the answer with *full* information such that it can stand on its own two feet without just a link.  Explain how and why this answers the OP's question.

But do consider the situation - if you're *not* certain that the questions are similar then adding the same answer to each question is not the way to go.

Comment: "Deleting all of the answers seems sensible" -- no, we typically leave a single copy, unless the answer itself has other issues of course. In this particular case, the answers did have additional problems. The answers are pure library recommendations, and qualify as link-only answers. Reposting in this case is consequently not appreciated without some substantial editing. Sauce (10k+): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239454/6296561 https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239356/6296561 https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239431/6296561

Comment: Thanks for the facts there @Zoe - I'll revise my answer shortly.  I would imagine [in the face of ambiguity, refusing the temptation to guess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python) would be the better advice to follow, but this seems like a slam-dunk "delete 'em all" answer anyway.

Comment: I thought that re-posting an answer after a moderator deleted it would be considered rude or obnoxious.  My interpretation of their "pick one" was telling me what I *should have done,* not what I should do next.  Also, how would one know about custom flags, except by asking here?  And I'm not sure what additional information should be added; the question asked for how to accomplish something, and the answer is, "There's a tool for that."  I gave the tool's name, with a link, yes, but also the tool's name.  I'm not trying to be a jerk, but actually to understand the rules, for real.

Answer (score 14):

Posting exact duplicate answers automatically generates a flag for moderator attention ([Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/1099857)).

Generally, moderators delete all of the duplicates but leave one of the answers (typically the first one) undeleted.

As the moderator comment suggests, the better approach would be to post one answer and flag (or vote to close) the other questions as duplicates where applicable.

However, the reason all of the answers may have been deleted was due to this line:

> When I finally found the project I was looking for, I went back and answered those three SO questions with a link to the product in question, to help the original askers.

If all the answers just provided a link to a solution, they may have been considered [not an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392/1099857) or [very low quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167641/1099857) and deleted for that reason. It's likely that only 2 of the answers have the "Don't post duplicate answers" comment and one was deleted without it (but that's just a guess).

As always, a Meta post (like done here) seeking clarification or an "in need of moderator intervention" flag can be used to request for a specific answer to be undeleted. Though the flag may be declined if the answer would have been deleted for other reasons (like post quality).

Comment: It is not the case that only 2 have the "don't post duplicates" comment.  All do.  And I'm surprised to hear that a meta post can be used in these situations, because this one has 7 downvotes already.  Is it or is it not a valid course of action?

Comment: Well it was just a guess. I had not seen the links Zoe had commented when I wrote this answer. Though it appears [only one of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239454/15497888) has the "don't post duplicate" comment. I'm not sure why you're conflating post score with being able to ask on Meta. No one has ever voted to close or delete this question (which would be an indication that this was not an appropriate thing to ask on meta). It is certainly on-topic for Meta regardless of the post score -7 (+5/-12).

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the question: 3 nearly identical link-only answers were posted on 3 nearly identical recommendation requests. Moderator deleted all 3 answers (instead of expected "all but one" in the regular case of "posted duplicate answers").

The best course of action:

- before all it started, the right action was to close "request for tools" questions and possibly add a comment with the link to the tool (adding a comment with a link is very controversial as it encourages off-topic questions - make your own judgment). Since one of the questions worded in a way that is suitable for SO (asking for "how" instead of "recommend tool") writing a complete answer about the tool you found (including how one would use it to solve the question) was (and still is) and option.
- After the moderator deleted all answers, the expected action was to notice that answers were link-only answers and as such are deleted irrespective of whether those answers are duplicates or not.
- Alternatively posting on meta (as you did) to clarify what happened (and possibly request to review mod actions) is the right step.

What to do right now: celebrate the learning of more rules of SO (close off-topic questions, recommendations are off-topic, don't post links as answers, don't post duplicate answers). Since one of the questions is still open (two others are correctly closed by a moderator as "request for recommendations") you can write a complete answer there.

If you decide to update the answer that was deleted by a moderator (I would recommend that approach) edit the post first. When you feel the answer can stand on its own *without link* then flag the answer "need moderator attention" with a sentence about "post deleted by a moderator, please undelete" along with brief summary of why you think the post in the new state is good,  possibly add the link to this meta for details.

Current state of [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239454) does not look enough to me (as someone who does not know much about jupyter notebooks)  to be undeleted by a moderator (probably would be borderline-ok as initial version, but I expect more scrutiny after deletion/meta post). A couple of sentences that whatever default tool jupyter uses does not support terminal mode and some more information on newly suggested tool (i.e. sample usage). Note that if you happen to be related to the linked project you need to disclose your association (does not sound like it applies to your case, adding the warning just in case).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm just not sure how to follow this advice.  It seems to be saying, "remove the link from your original answer and add more descriptive text."  But the tool I recommended does exactly what the OP asked, so adding more descriptive text would just be talking for the sake of talking more.  And removing the link actually makes the answer *less* useful, not *more* useful, because then the OP has to go google it for themselves.  Is that really the recommended course of action?